# Why shouldn't I always use dynamic allocation in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Spark's dynamic allocation enables a more efficient use of resources. It is described here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#dynamic-resource-allocation

It is not a default, and must be set for each job.

What are the downsides of setting every job to use dynamic allocation by default? What effects might be seen if I change this setting for all my running jobs?

Comment: Most commercial distributions of Spark do enable dynamic allocation cluster-wide (via spark-defaults.conf), to optimize resource utilization. One case when it is _not_ suitable are Spark Streaming where number of partitions is fixed, and loosing (or adding additional for that matter) executors will cause problems.

Answer (score 3):

To understand it lets take a look at [Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamic-allocation)

Here you can find this:

> spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled   false(default)
> Whether to use dynamic resource
> allocation, which scales the number of executors registered with this
> application up and down based on the workload. For more detail, see
> the description here.
>
> This requires spark.shuffle.service.enabled or
> spark.dynamicAllocation.shuffleTracking.enabled to be set. The
> following configurations are also relevant:
> spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors,
> spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors, and
> spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors
> spark.dynamicAllocation.executorAllocationRatio

Default values for revelevant parameters are:

```
spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors = minExecutors
spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors = 0
spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors = infinite
spark.dynamicAllocation.executorAllocationRatio = 1
```

Lets take a look at executorAllocationRatio description:

> By default, the dynamic allocation will request enough executors to
> maximize the parallelism according to the number of tasks to process.
> While this minimizes the latency of the job, with small tasks this
> setting can waste a lot of resources due to executor allocation
> overhead, as some executor might not even do any work. This setting
> allows to set a ratio that will be used to reduce the number of
> executors w.r.t. full parallelism. Defaults to 1.0 to give maximum
> parallelism. 0.5 will divide the target number of executors by 2 The
> target number of executors computed by the dynamicAllocation can still
> be overridden by the spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors and
> spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors settings

So what may happen when you just turn dynamic allocation on?

Lets say you have a job which at some stage is doing repartition(2000). Number of cores avilable per executor is set to 2. What is Spark going to do with dynamic allocation enabled with default parameters? It will try to get as many executors as it needs for max paralellism. In this case it will be 2000/2 (number of tasks at given stage/number of cores per executor, executorAllocationRatio is set to 1 so i am skipping it) = 1000 executors.

I saw a real scenarios in which some jobs where taking a lot of resources to work on really small inputs just because dynamic allocation was turned on

Imo if you want to use it you should tune also other parameters and for sure limit maxExecutors, especially if you are not alone on your cluster and you dont want to waste time&resources. Sometimes overhead for creating new exeuctor is just not worth it